# [PHP] Замена слова в тексте на ссылку?

Tags: php

$data='test,test 1,test 2,test 3';//чтение строки в переменную

как теперь получить такой вариант ?

```
$result="a href=/search.php?d=test>test</a>, a href=/search.php?d=test+2>test 2</a>, <a href=/search.php?d=test+3>test 3</a>"
```

Можете показать в рабочем примере?

СПасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function link_builder(&$data_str, $index)
{

        $encoded = urlencode($data_str);
        $data_str = "<a href=\"/search.php?d=$encoded\">$data_str</a>";
}

$data_array = explode(',', $data);
array_walk( $data_array, 'link_builder'); // Теперь в $data_array ваши ссылки
```

Comment: если нужна строка, используйте implode():

    $result = implode(',', $data_array);